# How to do reminder (alarm) for certain date/time)

Tags: android

I am making an application that you create events and reminder has part of them. I am ok with the event creation but  I am not sure about to go with reminder.What do you use for it? If the application is closed can  I still have it running in the background (kind of like the android calendar)

Thank you very much

Comment: This might be of help to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android

And this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676854/create-reminder-in-android-app

This is found from one simple Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to schedule events. But when device is turned-off, all alarms are canceled, so you should have a BroadcastReceiver which will listen to BOOT_COMPLETED intent and re-schedule events(which should be stored somewhere: shared preferences or sqlite).

Comment: If I have the broadcast receiver then shouldn't I have my app open in the first place to schedule event?